# Integrate $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\cos x}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Although I have known that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty {{\sin x} \over x} \, dx = {\pi  \over 2}$, I have no idea how to work out $\displaystyle\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\cos x} \over x} \, dx$. How can I?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Please don't add `\displaystyle` to titles; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730/74908). The title is perfectly readable without it.

Comment: @epimorphic : \displaystyle appeared _twice_ in this title before I edited it.  After that it appeared only once. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, sorry, I only read the beginning of the part being edited. I guess the point still stands that it should be removed altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx,
$$
diverges.

To see this observe that
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx\ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{x}=\infty.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{x} \, dx = \operatorname{Ci}(x) + C,$$
where $\operatorname{Ci}$ is the [Cosine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).

Your integral does not converge on the interval $[0,\infty)$, since $\operatorname{Ci}(0)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{a \to \infty}\operatorname{Ci}(a)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The integral does not converge

simply the result is$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x} \, dx = \infty$$