# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos x-\cos x^2}{x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Recently, I met a integration below
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x-\sin x^2}{x}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x^{2}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi }{4}
\end{align*}
the same way seems doesn't work in
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos x-\cos x^2}{x}\mathrm dx$$
but why? Then how to evaluate it? Thx!

Comment: Not sure how to evaluate this analytically, but Wolfram Alpha gives the value

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x-\cos x^2}{x}dx = -\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos x}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ does not converge, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978558/integrate-displaystyle-int-0-infty-frac-cos-xx-dx) for a proof.

So we have to find another way to evaluate it.

I'll think about it and post a solution later.

---

**Solution:**
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos x-\cos x^2}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{\alpha }\frac{\cos x-\cos x^2}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }-\int_{0}^{\alpha }\frac{1-\cos x+\cos x^2-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }\left ( -\int_{0}^{\alpha }\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{\alpha }\frac{1-\cos x^2}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x \right )\\
&=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }\left ( -\int_{0}^{\alpha }\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\alpha^{2} }\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x \right )\\
&=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }\left \{ \mathrm{Ci}\left ( \alpha  \right )-\gamma -\ln\alpha +\frac{1}{2}\left [ \gamma +\ln\alpha  ^{2}-\mathrm{Ci}\left ( \alpha ^{2} \right ) \right ] \right \}\\
&=\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty }\left [ -\frac{\gamma }{2}+\mathrm{Ci}\left ( \alpha  \right )-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Ci}\left ( \alpha ^{2} \right ) \right ]\\
&=-\frac{\gamma }{2}
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{Ci}\left ( \cdot  \right )$ is [Cosine Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) and we can easily find that $\mathrm{Ci}\left ( \alpha  \right )$ goes to $0$ when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: I have never heard about the cosine integral, but thx anyway, I'll try to understand it.

Comment: @user407289 you're welcome!

Comment: One may ask to show that $Ci(x)=\gamma+\log(x)+\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}\,dt$.  Do you have any ideas?  I've posted a solution herein.

Answer (score 8):

We begin by noting that we can write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x^2)}{x}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix^2}}{x}\,dx-i\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(x^2)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix^2}}{x}\,dx-i\pi/4 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can write the right-hand side of $(1)$ as

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix^2}}{x}\,dx-i\pi/4 =\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x^2}}{x}\,dx \tag 2$$

Integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ with $u=e^{-x}-e^{-x^2}$ and $v=\log(x)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x^2}}{x}\,dx &=\int_0^\infty \log(x) e^{-x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty 2x\log(x)e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac12\gamma
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

---

> **NOTE:**

> In the note at the end of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100567/real-analysis-methodologies-to-show-gamma-2-int-0-infty-frac-cosx2-cos/2101763#2101763), I showed that $\gamma$ as given by $\gamma=-\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,\log(x)\,dx$ is equal to $\gamma$ as expressed by the limit $\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(-\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)$.

---

---

**EDIT:  A SECOND METHODOLOGY:**

It is straightforward to show that for $t>0$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x^t)-e^{-x^t}}{x}\,dx=0\tag3$$

Simply enforce the substitution $x^t\mapsto x$ to reduce the integral in $(3)$ to

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x^t)-e^{-x^t}}{x}\,dx=\frac1t \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$$

Then, exploiting a property of the Laplace Transform, we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,dx$$

which is easily evaluated as $0$.

Hence, we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x^2)-\cos(x)}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\tag4$$

The integral on the the right-hand side of $(4)$ is identical to the integral on the the right-hand side of $(2)$, from which we obtain the previous result!

Comment: Why does the Cauchy integral theorem (which one?) tell you: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix^2}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-i\pi/4=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$?

Comment: @FShrike Contour deformation

Comment: The obvious choice is to integrate along the imaginary axis $z=ix$ but that leaves one with $e^{-ix^2}$ rather than $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @FShrike Split the integral into two parts $\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx$ and $\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{ix^2}}{x}\,dx$.  Deform the first as you mentioned.  Deform the second along the segement from $e^{i\pi/4}\varepsilon$ to $e^{i\pi/4}R$.  Then, use circular arcs around $0$ to close the contours.